# Why is my Eclipse window titled "PyDev - Eclipse (unregistered)"?

Tags: eclipse, pydev, liclipse

After installing the [PyDev IDE](http://www.pydev.org/), my titlebar for Eclipse changed into `PyDev - Eclipse (UNREGISTERED)`

[image: PyDev - Eclipse (UNREGISTERED)]

I tried reinstalling [LiClipse](http://www.liclipse.com/), Eclipse, the PyDev addon, but Eclipse still appears to be unregistered.

**Why does Eclipse appear as unregistered?**

Comment: Where did you get it from, how did you install it? Did you get it from [LiClipse](http://www.liclipse.com/)?

Comment: I downloaded LiClipse
I installed eclipse then added PyDev addon
I get the same result.

Answer (score 4):

You get the (UNREGISTERED) there because you're using [LiClipse](http://www.liclipse.com) without an actual license.

LiClipse is a commercial product which requires a license for continued use after the trial is finished. Conversely, [PyDev](http://www.pydev.org/) is open source and can work in any Eclipse installation. (PyDev is bundled with LiClipse by default).

You should either [buy a LiClipse license](http://www.liclipse.com/buy.html) or [install the plain Eclipse](https://www.eclipse.org/) with only the [PyDev plugin](http://www.pydev.org/) (not LiClipse).